# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer when I am start tomcat server in eclipse

Tags: java, xml, apache, tomcat

I will provide you below link to get my log file and screenshot.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3A4t_pDfpXrd0hSWXhfU052Q3c/view?usp=sharing

here I am using jar files Tomcat/lib files only using configure build path and select server run time library.

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package javax.servlet.jsp is sealed
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.getAndVerifyPackage(URLClassLoader.java:399)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.definePackageInternal(URLClassLoader.java:419)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.(JasperInitializer.java:51)
    ... 38 more

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.loadServices(WebappServiceLoader.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1661)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1138)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:775)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5003)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 27 more

Comment: Don't use screenshots. Please insert relevant code and output directly into your question.

Comment: I am also providing log file by link.

Comment: Don't link it, you should insert log output directly in the question. But only the part that is relevant to answer it.

Comment: ok I will put only necessary part of log and Thanks for guiding me

Comment: @JohannesMüller please check I will edit my question content as per your suggestion.